# Chat scrolls to the top and then back every time I post a message

Tags: support, chat, google-chrome

This only started recently. I'm using Chrome. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Posting because multiple people reported this problem independently; all times, this was the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you're using the [Screenshot Capture extension by Google](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg). Uninstall it and try an alternative (such as [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki)).

Comment: another idea is using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hccbinpobnjcpckmcfngmdpnbnjpmcbd#) (thanks to @Nyuszika7H for finding it) and enabling the extension only when needed.