# New chat messages always scroll up and down bug

Tags: bug, chat, google-chrome, osx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chat scrolls to the top and then back every time I post a message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80239/chat-scrolls-to-the-top-and-then-back-every-time-i-post-a-message)

Every time there's a chat message, instead of getting just a scroll down the screen scrolls up as well. So it makes a very annoying flickering up and down. With an active chat, it doesn't stop scrolling, making the whole chat experience absolutely terrible.

I'm surprised I couldn't find anyone else reporting or fixing this yet as I'm not an active chat user and this bug must be around for some time already.

I'm using always updated Google Chrome latest stable release (currently at 9.0.597.107) on an also updated Mac.