# Chat window scrolls up and down on new messages in Google Chrome Canary

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, google-chrome

The answers of the, as duplicate, linked questions haven't helped me first.

Looking at the linked [Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80239/chat-scrolls-to-the-top-and-then-back-every-time-i-post-a-message)

The accepted Answer says

> The issue is you're using the Screenshot Capture extension by Google. Uninstall it and try an alternative (such as this).

However. I have no such extension installed.

In the JavaScript Chatroom, i was [told](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12231357#12231357)

> That happens in chrome 30+

Though testing it with different versions *(stable, beta, canary)*, seems to reduce the problem to the canaray version.

---

I figured it is `jQuery.fn.animate` which is causing the trouble. [*(if you want to see)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmCQh.gif)

It is being called somewhere in the `jQuery.fn.scrollTo` function which gets redefined in [`master-chat.js`](http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Js/master-chat.js)

```
function h(a) { 
   i.animate(l, d, f.easing, a && function() {
      a.call(this, c, f)
   })
}
```

So to fix it temporarily it seems to be enough passing `0`as duration

```
function h(a) {
    i.animate(l, 0, f.easing, a && function() {
      a.call(this, c, f)
   })
}
```

Calling the first IIFE of `master-chat.js` with the workaround, via a bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function(e){function t(e){return"object"==typeof e?e:{top:e,left:e}}var n=e.scrollTo=function(t,n,r){e(window).scrollTo(t,n,r)};n.defaults={axis:"xy",duration:1.3<=parseFloat(e.fn.jquery)?0:1};n.window=function(){return e(window)._scrollable()};e.fn._scrollable=function(){return this.map(function(){if(this.nodeName&&-1==e.inArray(this.nodeName.toLowerCase(),["iframe","#document","html","body"]))return this;var t=(this.contentWindow||this).document||this.ownerDocument||this;return e.browser.safari||"BackCompat"==t.compatMode?t.body:t.documentElement})};e.fn.scrollTo=function(r,i,s){"object"==typeof i&&(s=i,i=0);"function"==typeof s&&(s={onAfter:s});"max"==r&&(r=9e9);s=e.extend({},n.defaults,s);i=i||s.speed||s.duration;s.queue=s.queue&&1<s.axis.length;s.queue&&(i/=2);s.offset=t(s.offset);s.over=t(s.over);return this._scrollable().each(function(){function o(e){l.animate(v,0,s.easing,e&&function(){e.call(this,r,s)})}var u=this,l=e(u),h=r,p,v={},m=l.is("html,body");switch(typeof h){case"number":case"string":if(/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(h)){h=t(h);break}h=e(h,this);case"object":if(h.is||h.style)p=(h=e(h)).offset()}e.each(s.axis.split(""),function(e,t){var r="x"==t?"Left":"Top",i=r.toLowerCase(),a="scroll"+r,c=u[a],d=n.max(u,t);p?(v[a]=p[i]+(m?0:c-l.offset()[i]),s.margin&&(v[a]-=parseInt(h.css("margin"+r))||0,v[a]-=parseInt(h.css("border"+r+"Width"))||0),v[a]+=s.offset[i]||0,s.over[i]&&(v[a]+=h["x"==t?"width":"height"]()*s.over[i])):(r=h[i],v[a]=r.slice&&"%"==r.slice(-1)?parseFloat(r)/100*d:r);/^\d+$/.test(v[a])&&(v[a]=0>=v[a]?0:Math.min(v[a],d));!e&&s.queue&&(c!=v[a]&&o(s.onAfterFirst),delete v[a])});o(s.onAfter)}).end()};n.max=function(t,n){var r="x"==n?"Width":"Height",i="scroll"+r;if(!e(t).is("html,body"))return t[i]-e(t)[r.toLowerCase()]();var r="client"+r,s=t.ownerDocument.documentElement,o=t.ownerDocument.body;return Math.max(s[i],o[i])-Math.min(s[r],o[r])}})(jQuery)
```

isn't the optimal way to get around this though. Since the canary version is not supported, this is probably not going to be fixed, so if anyones' using it and experience the problem, you can use the above code, either as bookmarklet or userscript, to temporarily get rid of the problem.

<sub>It seems the question can be closed then</sub>

Comment: I am using win7 chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 m and I don't see this occurring in chat.

Comment: @TravisJ hm, I'm on win 8.1 Chrome Canary 32.x,  I'll test it with different versions and update the question

Comment: Please note that Chrome Canary is not supported. I can't replicate on Chrome current (30).

Comment: @Sklivvz Thanks for the info, that makes sense. I tested it with each update channels' version. And it seems only to occur on canary. So i guess the question can be closed.

Comment: @Sklivvz [meta-tag:status-bydesign] or [meta-tag:status-declined] then? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I guess `will not be implemented or fixed at the present time.` is the better fit than  `is intentional`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 the lack of support is by design though. :)

Comment: It occurs in dev channel too, or at least the build I have. I went with the simpler approach of using `$.fx.off` to just disable all animations as a desperate workaround for now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That is indeed the case =) But i think the tags content' takes reference to the actual bug, rather than the fixing process of the bug. So while not to fix the bug is is inteded, the bug itself rather isn't =) btw thanks for updating the infos.

Comment: We don't support beta browsers. It is not worth working around bugs that are anyway most of the time fixed in the official release of the same browser.